# How do I disable --version-script when cross compiling clang/LLVM on a Mac?

Tags: macos, clang, llvm, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile my clang/LLVM based [ELLCC cross development tools project](http://ellcc.org) on a Mac. I am targeting ARM/Linux. The build fails while building FileCheck (or tbl-gen or any of the other build tools built during the cross-compile-build-tools step) because the build rules try to pass the --version-script option to the linker. There is a lot of configure magic going on and I can't seem to find the spell that says not to use --version-script on a Mac.

A little clarification of my problem. ELLCC builds fine on a Mac and creates executables that can be used to create ARM/Linux programs (or Mips/Linux, Microblaze/Linux, PowerPC/Linux, etc). The trouble I'm having is when I try to make ELLCC compile itself for the target.

clang/LLVM needs several tools that it supplies that need to run on the build host. Those tools are being compiled properly as Mac executables using the native Mac clang, but the link stage is mixed up and trying to use --version-script even though the Mac linker doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

You practically had the magic flag (or spell) in your title. I think you might be looking for:

```
   --disable-ld-version-script
```

There are also suggestions and considerations that deal with cross-compiling which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/porting/conceptual/portingunix/compiling/compiling.html) (section Cross-Compiling a Self-Bootstrapping Tool might be of relevance).

Comment: Almost correct, but thanks for the information. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is a problem with the rules used to cross build stuff. When I build for Linux on OS X, The variable HOST_OS is "Linux" in Makefile.rules. I had to add a Darwin conditional:

```
ifeq ($(HOST_OS), $(filter $(HOST_OS), DragonFly Linux NetBSD FreeBSD GNU/kFreeBSD GNU))
ifneq ($(shell uname -s),Darwin)
ifneq ($(ARCH), Mips)
  LD.Flags += -Wl,--version-script=$(LLVM_SRC_ROOT)/autoconf/ExportMap.map
endif
endif
endif
endif
```

There probably should be a BUILD_OS vs. HOST_OS, or HOST_OS is set incorrectly here.